# How to change the end of a URL in iOS Safari?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

When I am on a page in Safari, e.g. `https://example.com/somewhat-long-url/page-1` what's the fastest way to go to a different page: `https://example.com/somewhat-long-url/page-22`

Clicking the URL selects all of it, but doesn't scroll to the end it just shows the start of the URL.

If I tap again, it shows the selection handles. I can drag the start handle to the end of the URL, which moves infuriatingly slowly. When I bring the start handle on top of the end handle and let go it finally turns into a cursor at the end of the URL and I can start typing.

I have found only one other "solution": use force click on my keyboard to summon a cursor and then move the cursor to the end of the URL. This is similarly slow to do.

Both of these methods are too slow and frustrating for me.

How can I just jump to the end of the URL to edit text there?

Rather, what's the easiest/fastest way to edit text at the end of the URL of the page I am currently on and then visit that new URL?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try doing 3 quick taps on the selected text and it will take you to the end, then double click on the last character/word and edit.

Answer (score -3):

3 quick clicks highlights the whole url, then press cursor left/right to position the cursor at the beginning/end of the url string.

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/426417/237

Comment: Also: if you already have a keyboard connected to your iOS device (to press cursor left/right), why not just use Cmd-L to jump to the address bar in the first place?